# Как скопировать определённые файлы с папками в которых они лежат?

Tags: python-3.x, файловая-система, shutil

Подскажите пожалуйста, **как я могу скопировать определённые файлы**, скажем, заканчивающиеся на "_0.dds" **вместе с папками в которых этот файл лежит**?

Поскольку путей к файлам и директорий много то метод `os.listdir()` мне не очень помогает, а метод `shutil.copytree()` копирует все файлы без исключения.

Пример кода, который я пробовал:

```
import os
import shutil


for adress, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\1\\a_ui\\data\\ui'):
    for file in files:
        filename = os.path.join(adress, file)
        if "_0.dds" in filename:
            shutil.copy2(filename, 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\1\\a_ui\\aassets')
        #     shutil.copytree(adress, "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\1\\a_ui\\aASSETS")
        if "_2.dds" in filename:
            pass

print("DONE!")
```

Comment: Здесь всё есть - https://pynative.com/python-copy-files-and-directories/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подробно описал в комментариях алгоритм

Попробуйте:

```
import shutil
from pathlib import Path


# Задаем папки: откуда ищем и куда копируем
source_dir = Path(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\1\a_ui\data\ui')
target_dir = Path(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\1\a_ui\aassets')

# Поиск выполняется рекурсивно по шаблону
# На всякий оборачиваем в list, т.к. rglob возвращает генератор и возможна ситуация 
# рекурсивного создания одинакового дерева папок, 
# когда в source_dir и target_dir папки совпадают
for file_name in list(source_dir.rglob('*_0.dds')):
    # Получаем относительный путь от найденного файла к source_dir и составляем новый путь
    new_file_name = target_dir / file_name.relative_to(source_dir)
    
    # Берем папку файла и создаем ее, включая вложенность, не ругаемся, если папка уже есть
    new_file_name.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    shutil.copy2(file_name, new_file_name)
```

Comment: Приседание с list у вас скорее всего быть лишним и можно будет оставить `for file_name in source_dir.rglob('*_0.dds'):` - тут нужно смотреть по ситуации. У меня поиск был внутри папки и копировались файлы в специальную папку этой же папки и это породило рекурсию, т.к. rglob постоянно находил новые пути, порождая новые деревья папок с вложенными деревьями :)

Comment: Спасибо, это работает как надо и большое спасибо, что разъяснили работу метода rglob!

Comment: @Rett_oo, пожалуйста :)